# Unable to Connect iOS Device to macOS via USB pass-through in PVE 7

Tags: ios, usb, macos-big-sur, proxmox, pass-through

I installed PVE 7 on Debian 11 and configured hardware passthrough. Using [netmuxd](https://github.com/jkcoxson/netmuxd) on Linux, I can successfully connect to iOS devices, and I can see my iPad using `lsusb`.

```
madray@nas-debian-11:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:12ab Apple, Inc. iPad 4/Mini1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, it doesn't work on macOS installed in PVE (BigSur version), no matter if I use PCI passthrough for the device or directly passthrough the USB port, I still cannot make Xcode detect my iPad.

I have tested with USB flash drives and keyboard-mouse, and they work fine, confirming that USB passthrough is functional. Is there anything else I need to do? Thank you!

Comment: I encountered the same issue. My setup is PVE 7.1 + MacOS 13.3.1 with USB passthrough. Similarly, while this USB port can detect a keyboard and mouse, it cannot connect to my iPad device.